# module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Foreignkey'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new to Django and I just started learning it using Djaango by example but I am getting error messages.
Here is my Traceback

```
C:\Users\Harsley\shop>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Harsley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Harsley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Harsley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Harsley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Users\Harsley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Harsley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Harsley\shop\shops\models.py", line 16, in <module>
    class Product(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Harsley\shop\shops\models.py", line 17, in Product
    category = models.Foreignkey(Category,related_name='products')
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Foreignkey'
```

This is the model file and I have gone through it and it seems that I did not make any error. i

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

        def ___str__(self):
            return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.Foreignkey(Category,related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 3):

You misspelled `ForeignKey` in your code, `k` should be capital.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Information form above is , ForeignKey(k is captial)

Comment: The real issue was he misspelled `ForeignKey()` as `Foreignkey()`